# Scripting a players position (moving a object around on the screen)

Tags: javascript

Im looking into a small javascript game and is currently making a tool for testing "sqeuences" (game scenes where i want the script to move the player around thru waypoints, gonna call it actionscenes :D).

I think I almost got it right, but as you can see if you copypaste the code to a html the logic is broken. I need help with the trigonometric calculations:

http://pastebin.com/TfGU85ru

Any helpful tips? :D

It uses JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the quadrant you will also have to rotate the values `a` and `b` in the degree calculation. If the quadrant rotates 90 degrees, `a` and `b` have to be exchanged.

Also why use

```
var a = Math.pow( waypoint_x-player_x, 2);
var b = Math.pow( waypoint_y-player_y, 2);
```

and not

```
var a = Math.abs( waypoint_x-player_x);
var b = Math.abs( waypoint_y-player_y);
```

Comment: im rotating the correct way (me thinks, run it... it "works" kinda", but i dont understand why (after waypoint 1) that it goes down THEN towards WP3, it should have gone alon the hypotenuse (straight from WP2 to WP3)

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for? I highlighted the lines, http://pastebin.com/QyNebNqT

Comment: WOW... just what i asked for! I also understand it now, thank you so much!